# .replace in not working in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, ecmascript-6, meanjs

I have data as

```
var data = '<template type="amp-mustache">
      <div class="comment-item pull-left bottommargin10">
         <div> 
            <span class="comment-user-logo pull-left">{{title}}</span>
              <div class="pull-left margin-left-7">
                 <span class="comment-name">{{user.displayName}}</span>
                 <div class="comment-date">{{newDate}}</div>
                 <div class="comment-msg">{{message}}</div>
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </template>';
```

When I try to replace it

```
var newData = data.replace('<template type="amp-mustache">','');
```

It throws the following error

> data.replace is not a funtion

Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: `data` is not of type string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.toString()` to cast `data` to string. Once `.toString()` applied you can call `replace()` method.

Check this fiddle i created for easier understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/6sxf5d29

Answer (score 2):

You need to use backticks for multiline strings. See [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
var data = `<template type="amp-mustache">
      <div class="comment-item pull-left bottommargin10">
         <div> 
            <span class="comment-user-logo pull-left">{{title}}</span>
              <div class="pull-left margin-left-7">
                 <span class="comment-name">{{user.displayName}}</span>
                 <div class="comment-date">{{newDate}}</div>
                 <div class="comment-msg">{{message}}</div>
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </template>`;

console.log(data.replace('<template type="amp-mustache">',''));
```

Comment: but I am getting this as a response from my server call